# Adjusting the Spacing Between Headings, Entries, and Subentries with Idxlayout

Tags: spacing, indexing, makeindex, vertical-spacing, idxlayout

Consider the code

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.mst}
%delim_0 "\\IndexDotfill "
%delim_1 "\\IndexDotfill "
headings_flag 1
heading_prefix "  \\IndexHeading{"
heading_suffix "}\n"
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage 

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage{idxlayout}


\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes.callouts,shapes.arrows}

\newcommand*{\IndexDotfill}{%
  \nobreak\dotfill\ \nobreak
}
\renewcommand*{\indexspace}{%
  \par
  \vspace{25pt plus 6pt minus 4pt}%
  }
\newcommand*{\IndexHeading}[1]{%
\vspace{27pt}
\hfil   \tikz\node[
    rounded corners=5pt,
    draw=red,
    fill=red!65,
    line width=1.3pt,
    inner sep=10pt,
    align=center,
    font=\sffamily\bfseries\Large,
    minimum width=1.25in
  ] {#1};%
  \nopagebreak
  \par
  \vspace{2mm}%
\hfil }


% Make all page numbers in index bold
\let\oldindex\index
\renewcommand{\index}[1]{%
  \oldindex{#1|textbf}%
}%

\begin{document}
\LARGE

\newpage A sentence.\index{Entry Heading@\textbf{\textcolor{black}{Entry Heading}}!Statement containing a subentry}
\index{Entry Heading@\textbf{\textcolor{black}{Entry Heading}}!Statement containing another subentry}
\index{Entry Heading@\textbf{\textcolor{black}{Entry Heading}}!Statement containing yet another subentry}

Another sentence.\index{Second Entry Heading@\textbf{\textcolor{black}{Second Entry Heading}}!Statement containing a subentry}
\index{Second Entry Heading@\textbf{\textcolor{black}{Second Entry Heading}}!Statement containing another subentry}
\index{Second Entry Heading@\textbf{\textcolor{black}{Second Entry Heading}}!Statement containing yet another subentry}
    
\idxlayout{columns=1}
%\idxlayout{columns=1,notesep=50pt}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

which produces the Index

[image]

I would like to be able to adjust the spacing between the Entry Headings and the subsequent subentries. After consulting the Idxlayout documentation, I thought the *notesep* command might be what I want, but when I uncomment out `%\idxlayout{columns=1,notesep=50pt}` and run the code with it---there is no apparent change in the space between each main entry and its subentries despite the ridiculously large value of 50pt.

QUESTION: Can anyone tell me how to adjust the spacing between (i) the main entry and the first subentry; (ii) the spacing, say, between the capital E and the First Entry; and (iii) the spacing between the last subentry of a given category and the following capital letter?

**Remark** I am looking for a way to do this from the set of *Options and commands* of the `idxlayout package`; e.g.,

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: The `notesep` option is meant for setting a space between the index title (which is just "Index" in your case) and a note that will appear directly underneath this index title (only one note for the whole index, that is) and which can be set using the macro `\setindexprenote`. I guess, this is not what you aim for.

Answer (score 1):

You could maybe place some `\vspace` into the .mst file. I don't know whether this is  really good practice, though.

I marked the different lines where you can adjust vertical spacings. I cleaned up you code a bit and removed stuff that is not really necessary for this example.

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.mst}
item_x1 "\n\\vspace{20pt}\\subitem "   % <-- spacing between level 0 and level 1 entry
headings_flag 1
heading_prefix "\\IndexHeading{"
heading_suffix "}\n"
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage 

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage{idxlayout}

\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes.callouts,shapes.arrows}

%\renewcommand*{\indexspace}{%
%  \par
%  \vspace{25pt plus 6pt minus 4pt}%  % <-- spacing between index groups
%}
\newcommand*{\IndexHeading}[1]{%
\vspace{10pt}%                        % <-- spacing before heading box
\hfil
\tikz\node[
    rounded corners=5pt,
    draw=red,
    fill=red!65,
    line width=1.3pt,
    inner sep=10pt,
    align=center,
    font=\sffamily\bfseries\Large,
    minimum width=1.25in
  ] {#1};%
\nopagebreak
\par
\vspace{5pt}%                        % <-- spacing after heading box
\hfil }

% Make all page numbers in index bold
\let\oldindex\index
\renewcommand{\index}[1]{%
  \oldindex{#1|textbf}%
}%

\begin{document}
\LARGE

\newpage A sentence.\index{Entry Heading@\textbf{Entry Heading}!Statement containing a subentry}
\index{Entry Heading@\textbf{Entry Heading}!Statement containing another subentry}
\index{Entry Heading@\textbf{Entry Heading}!Statement containing yet another subentry}

Another sentence.\index{Second Entry Heading@\textbf{Second Entry Heading}!Statement containing a subentry}
\index{Second Entry Heading@\textbf{Second Entry Heading}!Statement containing another subentry}
\index{Second Entry Heading@\textbf{Second Entry Heading}!Statement containing yet another subentry}
    
\idxlayout{columns=1}
%\idxlayout{columns=1,notesep=50pt}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Many thanks for your answer. That is a way that works for one of the vertical spacing questions I posed; however, it seems that there should be a way to accomplish these things by adding some numerical parameters to  `\idxlayout{}`, but I couldn't figure out how to do that for the spacing issue you addressed. Your answer is helpful though. Thank you.

Comment: It seems that the parameters for `\idxlayout` don't provide a solution for this, since they primarily cope with the overall appearance of the index and don't address the spacing between entries of different levels (and this is essentially what you need). At least, I could not find a way to solve your problem only using these options.